# CSS extra horizontal white space

Tags: html, css, whitespace, horizontal-scrolling

On my website there's some extra horizontal space appearing on the right side when the window is resized and on mobile browsers. I've tried everything I can think of and I have no idea what might be causing it. The website is [here](http://www.oliverwhitehall.com/).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using google crome, everything looks fine to me.

if you are using ie then you might need to margin 0 padding 0 on a division. To seek the division causing trouble use developer tools and highlight the whitespace.

Comment: Yea, looks fine to me too - chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a dozen invalid CSS properties being used. Not to mention "http://www.oliverwhitehall.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)".

I would start there.

As far as resizing the browser, it does nothing. In addition, there is no horizontal scrollbar, so I cannot scroll to the right to see.